# Show list view in a page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, list-view

I have created a list in the site.
I want to display this list in a different view in a page.
Is there any way I could do it without SharePoint Designer and coding?
I tried to add list using insert WebPart but it does not allow me to have the desired view.
If I change it in the page, it changes in the original List.

Answer (score 3):

After you add the web part, click on *"Edit Web part"* from right top arrow.
[image] 

This will open the web part properties *(like given image)*, now you can select the desired view and click Apply --> Ok.

Comment: Thanks.
That's it. I was trying to Modify view from the List in ribbon.